# Scaling arc4random for different screen sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, arc4random

I'm making a game that doesn't use Autolayout, and have used constraints to scale everything and it worked perfectly. However I cant seem to figure this out, I'm using arc4random to randomly position X and Y coordinates of a UIButton on the 4.7 inch screen. When I try running it on the smaller screen it plots the UIButton off the screen at times. How can I scale arc4random up and down depending on screen size.

```
-(void)position{

     Randompositionx = arc4random() %270;
     Randompositionx = Randompositionx + 51;
     Randompositiony = arc4random() %411;
     Randompositiony = Randompositiony +163;

UIButton.center = CGPointMake(Randompositionx, Randompositiony);


}
```

Comment: Looks like you will have to mod out by numbers other than 270 and 411... Where are those magic numbers coming from?

Comment: You need to set the min and max position for your UIButton

Comment: Never, EVER use a variable name that's the same as a class name. That won't compile (your variable name "UIButton")

Comment: Also make sure all variable names start with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using arc4random_uniform rather than arc4random and the modulo operator. It gives numbers without "modulo bias".

You need to adapt the upper value of your random number based on screen size. T_77's answer was a step in the right direction, but still not right.

The code below assumes the button you want to move is called myButton.

It uses margin values of 20 all around. Change the values as desired.

EDIT: I updated it to use the height and width of the button in the position calculation. With the updated code the button should never be closer to any edge than the margin value, even if the button size changes. No magic numbers, either. It should adapt to the size of it's superview.

```
-(void)position
{
  CGRect frame = myButton.superview.bounds;
  CGFloat leftMargin = 20; //use whatever values you want for magins
  CGFloat rightMargin = 20;
  CGFloat topMargin = 20;
  CGFloat bottomMargin = 20;
  CGFloat randomX, randomY;
  CGFloat xMax = frame.size.width-leftMargin-rightMargin-
    button.bounds.size.width/2;
  randomX = arc4random_uniform(xMax) + leftMargin;
  CGFloat yMax = frame.size.height-topMargin-bottomMargin-
    button.bounds.size.height/2;
  randomY = arc4random_uniform(yMax) + topMargin; 
  myButton.center = CGPointMake(randomX, randomY);
}
```

Also note that if you're using auto layout  you shouldn't move the button's position directly, and instead should have position constraints and modify their constants, then call layoutIfNeeded. Otherwise the first thing that causes your layout to change will cause your button to revert to it's previous position.

Comment: Thank you very much Duncan, your explanation was great and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void)position{
   CGRect frame = [self.view frame];

 Randompositionx = arc4random() %270;
 Randompositionx = Randompositionx + CGRectGetMinX(frame);
 Randompositiony = arc4random() %411;
 Randompositiony = Randompositiony +CGRectGetMinY(frame);

   UIButton.center = CGPointMake(Randompositionx, Randompositiony);


}
```

Now you can position your UIButton within your view.

Comment: That still doesn't change the maximum range like it should.

Comment: I  thought to display the button within the view for now. @DuncanC

Comment: Thanks, but when I run it on the Iphone 4s the UIbutton is still displayed off the screen sometimes. It runs prefect on the Iphone 6 with the code I had first posted, never going off screen. The UIbutton is also 112x104.

Thank you all very much for your help.

Comment: The whole point is that the screen size changes on different devices, so the max value from the random number needs to adapt to the screen size (or the size of the superview, whichever is appropriate.) Your code doesn't do that.

Comment: you are right @DuncanC. I didn't look at the adaptability. As I am a junior developer I tried to contribute a small part of the answer.